# is it possible to make a link in a image clickable(.png or .jpeg file)

Tags: html, image, hyperlink

Is it possible to make a link or text in a image file clickable?
I am referring to the text in a image file like .png or .jpeg files and not a html page where text is over the image.
if it is please share some references. if not why?

Comment: Have you tried image maps? [HTML Image Maps](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_imagemap.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Shorthand, no you can't. Why? Because the text on an image is part of the image, you can reference the image itself, but not the text.

Answer (score 0):

JPEG and PNG files are data. There is no HTML embedded in it i.e. Anchor tags and hrefs.

Anatomy of a JPEG
https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/2017-01-31_jpeg/